# Design-time failure: WPF, Assembly Loading

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have 4 projects:

- Client (Wpf Application)
- Server (Console Application)
- ClientServerInterface (Class Library)
- Core (Class Library)

Client and Server references ClientServerInterface. 
Also Server reference Project "Core".

When I'm open WPF Designer in Client Project, designer says

"Could not load file or assembly 'Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Can not find the file specified."

But he does not have to load it. Not "Clent" nor it subreferences does not reference it!

Help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is it possible there is a config file that includes the assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something in the designer needs it so it tries to load it.  if you don't need the designer, then don't open it.  if you need to open the designer, then add the assembly to your references.